# Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am getting this error:

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something
>   async in your test?

in my simple test code in test file.

I am using nodejs request module to make request and after callback i am logging the response which throws this warning.

Following is my test case I'm using.

```
    request.get(
        {
            url:"", headers
        }, (err, data) => {
            if(err) console.log(err)
            if(data.statusCode != 200) console.log(data.body)
            console.log(data.body)
            expect(data.statusCode).toBe(200)
    })
})
```

Comment: You may want to post the complete code.  But request.get returns a Promise so it will need to be "awaited" upon or instead of the callback, you use the "then".  See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.

Comment: Got a solution. use Done() in the last.

Comment: Not sure if this is the library you're using because it's deprecated: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait)

Comment: What do you mean by 'use Done() in the last'? Thank you.

Comment: using done() as a callback function means the function has completed process and need to return, see concept of done in nodejs

Comment: @jazeb007, can you please share a code sample.